# How to run windows command from GitBash?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, git-bash

I am using Gitbash to run few jars and other windows command ,so I am trying to make a master.bat to run all these jars. Bat files run them on command prompt.Is there any way to run commands on git bash(not necessarily Git command)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to type e.g. ./yourbatname.bat on gitbash, if you're in that folder, otherwise yourpathToBatFile/yourbatname.bat

Answer (score 0):

By default, your .bat would not be executable.

You need:

```
chmod 775 yourScript.bat
./yourScript.bat
```